# Mocha + Sinon testing mongoose methods being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I have following function called on specific route and I am trying to test if the mongoose method inside is called with specific parameter.
My code:

```
import boom from 'boom'
import User from '../models/model.user'


export const getSingle = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.payload.id, '-auth')
        if (user) {
            return res.json({user})
        }
        return next(boom.notFound('User not found'))
    } catch (err) {        
        return next(boom.badImplementation('Something went wrong', err))
    }
}
```

My test case:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'
import 'babel-polyfill'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import sinon from 'sinon'
require('sinon-mongoose')
import { getSingle } from '../src/controllers/controller.user'
const User = mongoose.model('User')


describe('User Controller ----> getSingle', () => {
    it('Should call findById on User model with user id', async () => {
        const req = {
                    payload: {
                        id: '123465798'
                    }
                }
        const res = { json: function(){} }
        const next = function() {}
        const UserMock = sinon.mock(User)

        UserMock.expects("findById").once().withExactArgs('123465798', '-auth')
        await getSingle(req, res, next)           
        UserMock.verify()



    })
})
```

It fails the test as the method wasn't called even though it was.

Comment: Try importing the same model in your test as in the code under test i.e. `'../models/model.user'`

Comment: That I tried, but for some reason User then returns empty object. This way I'm at least see correct output.

Comment: What does the file `../models/model.user` look like?

Comment: File is alright, function works as is supposed, just can't get the test working. Anyway I will update my question with the user schema tomorrow.

Comment: You were right from all the moving code back and forward at the end I wasn't exporting the model, just registering. So if you will create this as an answer I will happily accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the same model in the test as is used in the code under test i.e `../models/model.user` and it should work as expected.